# How to handle callback for JSONP inside angularjs

Tags: angularjs, jsonp

I have a working JSONP call inside a angularjs module to get working I defined the callback outside of the module (see below). I was unable to get the callback working inside the module ( callback not defined ).

How would I get the `jsonp_callback(data)` inside the angular module ?

```
function jsonp_callback(data) {
// returning from async callbacks is (generally) meaningless
alert('good');
console.log(data.found);
}


angular.module('me.services', [])
.factory('Products', ['$http', '$q', '$filter', function ($http, $q, $filter) { // Query API and return JSON.
    return {
        get: function () {
            var _deferred = $q.defer(),
                funds = [],
                products = [];

            var murl = "http://localhost:82/api/productlist/getitems";
            $http.jsonp(murl + "?callback=jsonp_callback", null, function (result) {
                alert('ts');
            });
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you want to handle the data inside angular:

```
function jsonp_callback(data) {

  // for binding to a service property
  angular.element(document).injector().get('ServiceName').whatever = data

  // for binding to a controller scope propery
  angular.element('#someDiv').scope().whatever = data

  ...
```